# How to display an array with AngularJs in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript array like the following:

```
var array = [
   2005 = [
       Jan = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       Feb = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       ...more
   ], 
   2006 = [
       Jan = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       Feb = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       ...more
   ], 
   2007 = [
       Jan = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       Feb = [0,1,2,3,5...],
       ...more
   ]

]

$scope.cal = array;
```

I am trying to build a calendar with ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat = "year in cal">
    {{year}}
</div>
```

There is nothing output and I got an error

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. 
Repeater: year in cal, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined
```

I am not sure what I did wrong and my brain is fried. Please help me out on this one. Thanks!

Comment: `<div ng-repeat = "year in cal track by $index">`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha I did try that, all I got is 3 lines of []

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha not sure what your question mean. I got [] [] [] for three different divs

Comment: your array is not valid i think

Comment: when I console.log(array) it displays fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63906/discussion-between-kalhano-toress-pamuditha-and-bonjon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a common property between the different year entries that you can bind to. So you need some kind of a value property which holds the identifier like the year or the month and another property that holds the value array. See the example below.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cal = [
        {
            value: 2005,
            month:
            [
                {
                    value: 'Jan',
                    days: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                },
                {
                    value: 'Feb',
                    days: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            value: 2006,
            month:
            [
                {
                    value: 'Jan',
                    days: [0, 1, 3, 7]
                },
                {
                    value: 'Feb',
                    days: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat = "year in cal">
          Year: {{year.value}}
          <div ng-repeat = "month in year.month">
              Month: {{month.value}}
              <div ng-repeat = "day in month.days">
                Day: {{day}}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5whdli2CP8fAfBu8LfVg?p=preview)

Apart from the syntax problems of JSON object the design should be something like this:

```
    [
        {
           yearNum: 2005,
           months: [
                        {Jan : [0,1,2,3,5]},
                        {Feb : [0,1,2,3,5]},
                      ]
        }, 
        {
           yearNum: 2006,
           months: [
                        {Jan : [0,1,2,3,5]},
                        {Feb : [0,1,2,3,5]},
                      ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! but Denis's is better for what I need! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting you array like this.

```
var array = [
   { 2005: [
      { Jan: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5] },
      { Feb: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5] },
   ]
}];
```